# How to redirect to a query link with a button?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom

I'm working on a project that has got "example.com/data/?name=xx&location=yy" query url. I made this with a get method for making project more easier. But I've been stuck with a little problem. I can't redirect to that url with form data.

I have tried getting form's input values with

```
var nameInput = document.getElementById("productNameInput").value;
```

and then I combined these values into a url. Then, I made a redirect call for these url but it didn't work.

```js
document.getElementById("buttonID").onclick = function () {
  var nameInput = document.getElementById("productNameInput").value;
  var locationInput = document.getElementById("productLocaInput").value;
  var goToURL = "http://example.me/data/add/?" + "name=" + nameInput + "&" + "location=" + locationInput;

   window.location.replace(goToURL);
    };
```

But there's no error messages or something. When I pressed that button, suddenly page refresh and nothing has done.

Comment: Does the button have a `type="submit"` on it?

Comment: `window.location.replace()` doesn't work that way. It won't replace the entire URL in the address bar, just the current resource.  

That is to say if you are currently at :
`google.com/drive`
`window.location.replace("google.com/maps")`
will attempt to navigate to:
`google.com/google.com/maps`

Answer (score 0):

window.location.href =goToURL; is how ?

Answer (score 0):

**if you dont't want to refresh your page you can try this**

```
const queryString = `?name=${nameInput}&location=${locationInput}`
history.pushState(null, null, queryString);
```

---

see [history API]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API